# Is linux any good for programming?

Tags: linux

I'm thinking of buying a netbook with linux installed for school and at home, but i'm not sure. Because i want to use it for things such as word as well as doing some coding.

Is there a terminal in it?

I've also heard that it can't run .exe is this true?

P.s what are the best linux netbooks and operating system? Thanks!

I would like to program in:

Python

Javascript

Ruby

and also would like to do some web development

Comment: I think this question would be better off at Super User. Maybe we can migrate this? And please edit your question to brush it up a little, so that it looks nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Programming

I think that Linux is really great for programming. Installing other libraries is really a breeze. I would wholehardedly recommend Linux for Programming in:

- C
- C++
- Python
- Java
- PHP
- JavaScript
- Haskell
- Lua
- Lisp

You can also do C# with the Mono toolchain, but I am not sure how compatible that is with the C# and .NET from Windows.

On Windows, I find programming a pain. C does not really work (unless you use Visual Studio maybe), Java works pretty well. Python works also kind of well.

If you want to develop games that run with DirectX, Windows is your only option. OpenGL seems powerful as well, and that runs everywhere.

## Word

Doing “Word” stuff should be okay with LibreOffice or OpenOffice.org. It might not be super compatible with Microsoft Word, but you should do fine.

## Linux Distro

Go with Ubuntu, maybe Xubuntu or Lubuntu on a Netbook. If you do not like Ubuntu, openSUSE and Fedora would be my next recommendations.

## Hardware

Try to get as much Intel hardware as possible, that usually works flawlessly.

Comment: Are you sure that he asked about programming lang's? I understood that he asked about OS.

Comment: He did, but “programming” is such a broad field. And the OS I would recommend depends on the programming language. If somebody really wanted to do Visual Basic or Powershell, you have no alternative than Windows.

Answer (score -1):

All of them.

For newbies I recommend Debian or Ubuntu but it depends on personal preferences.

Ubuntu has app center where you can find a lot of useful apps. Ubuntu has also great support for graphic interface.

Try it for free [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop).